# Does anyone have any idea what this device might be?

Tags: identification, test-equipment

I recently got a box of vintage stuffs. I came across this stuff. Its powered by a 9V battery. Does anyone has any idea what this is?

[image: IMG 1]

[image: IMG 2]

Comment: Hm. "m/s" - minutes/seconds? A stopwatch?

Comment: meters/s? are the two holes in the bottom optical sensors for measuring the speed of a moving object?

Comment: Can you put a battery in and see what it does? Well, there is a little chance it will explode...

Comment: It was a big box with so so many items. I'm yet to sort all the other items like  intel 80386 mobs, TI55, TI59 etc etc . I'll try to see if I can find anything that can into those two holes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes I tried putting the battery and it just showed "00.0". That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most likely a display armature for an anemometer. *Wilh. Lamprecht, Göttingen* produces all kind of weather science equipment.

Comment: meters/seconds. Makes sense.

Comment: You guys are right. It probably might be, but this particular instrument is nowhere to be seen on the google searches.

Comment: @Janka You were right the top part is missing. I connected a motor to it with a fan and placed it in front of continuous air flow to generate current and that gave me reading on the meter. Though I'm not sure if it works by the same principle. When you suggested that its an anemometer it gave me this idea as most modern anemometers have that electric fan.